# Fill out missing value within groups SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called 'test' that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwK3f.png)

and i want to create a view to make it into a table like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TT2Y.png)

which basically is that if the student didn't take that subject's test, still keep it in there and the score is null.

I'm pretty new to SQL and anyone has any thoughts?
Thank you so much .

I tried using left outer join but it's not working....

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

If you can break the table into two tables, one with subjects and one with scores, then it is possible to do this in a few queries.

```
create table subjects (subjectid int, subject varchar(20));
insert into subjects (subjectid, subject) values (1, 'chinese');
insert into subjects (subjectid, subject) values (2, 'math');
insert into subjects (subjectid, subject) values (3, 'english');

create table scores (userid int, subjectid int, score int);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (1, 1, 80);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (1, 2, 99);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (1, 3, 88);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (2, 1, 55);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (2, 2, 66);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (2, 3, 87);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (3, 1, 100);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (3, 2, 54);
insert into scores (userid, subjectid, score) values (4, 1, 86);

create temporary table t1 
  (select scores.userid, subjects.subjectid, subjects.subject
  from subjects, scores 
  group by userid, subjectid, subject
  order by userid, subjectid);

select t1.userid, t1.subject, scores.score
  from t1
  left outer join scores
  on scores.userid=t1.userid and scores.subjectid=t1.subjectid
  order by t1.userid, t1.subjectid;
```